# react native problem with creating apk: gradle mergeDexRelease

Tags: react-native, gradle

My app works well on `react-native-run-android` and on `gradlew clean` provide me build success.

I used to check and creating the apk by using `gradlew assembleRelease`.

Recently, I faced an error while trying to create the APK and I cant find the right solution.

as far as I understand, some problem with the build.gradle or any gradle settings - the last feature I put was the mauron background geolocation (im not sure if that cause the problem).

I tried:

1. on gradle.properties :

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

2. 

in build.gradle I added: `implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'` in the dependencies.

3.

```
 defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        // multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

The gradle I used was 6.3. So I upgraded (downloaded from their website v7 but I think the project is still under 6.3).

My question is:

If the app works and build successfuly, **was the error because of my code or the gradle settings?**

Im over a week with that problem and out of any clue how to get it work.

the error I get:

```
> Task :app:mergeDexRelease FAILED
D8: Program type already present: org.apache.commons.io.Charsets
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
Program type already present: org.apache.commons.io.Charsets
```

full picture: https://ibb.co/87pFnv1 , https://ibb.co/FxB8PWX

could anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not about multidex. It clearly says that one of your package is trying to add a library which is already there.

Since you have the name of the library you can put conditional implementation in your build.gradle to avoid redundant implementation.

for example

Implementation('new package that has module'){
exclude module: 'module to exclude'
}

Comment: I removed that background package and seem to work. maybe something in the settings causing duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the problem, Thanks Shashank Shekhar for directing me to the correct problem.

I used mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation package, was working fine until I tried to create apk.

in mauron85 issue #505 there was similar problem and someone fixed it by forking and maintaining the repo.

if anyone face that issue in future, I recommend to use @darron1217/react-native-background-geolocation as it solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: I have two packages `@react-native-masked-view/masked-view` (from previous developer) and `@react-native-community/masked-view`. Just remove `@react-native-masked-view/masked-view` package and try build.

https://github.com/react-native-masked-view/masked-view/issues/100#issuecomment-841634389 Thanks to: Navipro70